# How to simulate click event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I’ve created a `KeyboardEvent`, with the `ctrlKey` set to true and the code for the S key, then tried running `document.dispatchEvent(e)` to try to simulate the `ctrl + S` shortcut, but the event listener doesn’t seem to pick this up. Is there another way to simulate this event?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) { console.log(event.which); });

        onkeydown = function (e) {
            if (e.ctrlKey && (e.which == 'S'.charCodeAt(0) || e.which == 's'.charCodeAt(0))) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("CTRL + S was pressed")
            }
        }

        function buttonClick() {
            var e = new KeyboardEvent("event", { 'ctrlKey': true, 'which': 83 });
            document.dispatchEvent(e);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <button ID="Button1" onclick="buttonClick();">Test</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery in your project or just pure JavaScript?

Comment: Pure JavaScript, and is preferred.

Comment: [It seems to be picking it up](https://jsfiddle.net/gbwyath9/), as in the alert is showing. Exactly what is going wrong?

Comment: I'm referring to the event listener itself not picking up the simulation from the button `onclick` event. That should display the `keydown` event in the `console.log();`

Answer (score -1):

Use `code` attribute: http://codepen.io/topheman/pen/yJaGWv?editors=1001

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) { console.log(event.code, event.ctrlKey); });

        function buttonClick() {
            var e = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", { 'ctrlKey': true, 'which': 83, 'code': 83 });
            document.dispatchEvent(e);
        }
</script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <button ID="Button1" onclick="buttonClick();">Test</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer? Why use `code`?